# State of button controlled by a check-box

Tags: user-interface, mfc

I have a dialog box with a check-box and a button. I want to make the button enabled/disabled depending on the state of the check-box.
I have tried achieving this using ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI:

```
...
DDX_Check(pDX, IDC_CHECK1, bFlag);
...
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(IDC_BUTTON1, OnUpdateButton1)
...
void ColorDialog::OnUpdateButton1(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
    pCmdUI->Enable(bFlag);
}
```

But nothing happens. Checking/unchecking the check-box does nothing to the button.
  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI is relevant only for menu items amd toolbar buttons. You have to add ON_BN_CLICKED to your message map.

Comment: that is `ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK1, ...)`, not `ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Add an eventhandler for checkbox-click, where you call

```
UpdateData(TRUE);
pButton->EnableWindow(bFlag);
```

This should do the trick.